# why adfs configuration required DC administrator

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, windows-server-2012-r2, adfs3.0

I plan to configure ADFS on my SharePoint server. I have separate AD DC. While configuring `adfs` in SharePoint it require my DC Admin password, Shall I give the admin password to configure, if this affects my AD schema or any changes?

Why the admin password is asking while configuring `adfs`

Your valuable reply helps us a lot.

Answer (score 1):

ADFS creates some entities on the DC to store passwords etc.

It needs domain admin rights to do this.